# Get absolute path of file in hdfs

Tags: hdfs

I want to know the absolute path (may include IP address also) of a file in `hdfs`. What is command for that ? I tried something using `readlink -f` previously (which worked), but i forgot what i did.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path of a HDFS file is `hdfs://<cluster>/user/xxx/...` where `<cluster>` is the logical name of the cluster in a H/A deployment

In case of non H/A deployment `<cluster>` is the Name Node's FQDN or its @IP

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to get :

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
```